# Converting to float without truncation

Tags: python, floating-point, truncate, floating-point-conversion

I am trying to calculate an error function with Python 2.7, it has a term such that;

```
...
sumNSSD = float()
sumNSSD = sumFiGi/sumGi2
return sumNSSD
```

`sumFiGi` and `sumGi2` are of type `int()` and `sumFiGi/sumGi2` results to be something between 0 and 1, lets say 3/4

When the code evaluates 3/4 it returns 0 because of truncation, and `sumNSSD` becomes `int()` again. When I try `sumNSSD = float(sumFiGi/sumGi2)` it still truncates and returns `0.0`

A solution that works is to type `sumNSSD = float(sumFiGi) / float(sumGi2)` but the actual equation is much longer and it doesn't make sense to put every term inside `float(...)`

There should be an obvious way for getting around the truncation, however, I did search a lot of topics but no question answers my problem.

*Using* `Decimal()` *produces the same result because it evaluates what is in between the parantheses first, then truncates and returns 0*

Even Python Documentation puts it this way;

> ```
> >>> from decimal import *  
> >>> getcontext().prec = 6  
> >>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)  
> Decimal('0.142857')
> ```

What would be a **simple** solution except putting every single term into `Decimal(...)` or `float(...)`

Comment: Consider `from __future__ import division`

Comment: Would be great if you added the tag **truncate** into the **how can I force division to be floating point in Python?** topic, since it was how I went on searching, being the reason of this problem